# How to pass hexadecimal data inside the following function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, hex

I have my following program that has a function that will extract the particular Bytes from a frame of 8 Bytes data and will give a corresponding value needed based on the start bit and bit length (length counted from the start bit).

How can i pass the data of 8 bytes which is in hexa decimal to my pointer *data in the main function.
For example this is my frame data in hexadecimal '05 00 00 00 00 03 E8 00'. Here is my program. Would be grat if someone help me to solve this. Should i take an array and pass the data as `0x05 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x03 0xE8 0x00` into the array and then give assign address of the array to the pointer variable? or just take a variable that holds `0x050000000003E800` and assign this address to the pointer.Are the both same?   Thanks in advance.

```
union u_t
{
  uint16_t u16;
  uint8_t u8[2];
};
uint16_t Frame2Data(uint8_t *data,uint8_t startBit,uint16_t length)
{
  uint16_t mask;
  uint8_t start;
  uint8_t firstByte,offset;
  uint8_t numShift;
  union u_t ut;
  /*if(length == 8)     //preliminary, has to be fixed by correct function.  
    mask =  0xff;*/
  if(length == 7)
    mask = 0x7F;
  if(length == 10)
    mask = 0x3ff;
  if(length == 12)
    mask = 0xfff;

  firstByte = startBit / 8;
  offset = (firstByte+2) * 8;
  start = startBit + length;
  numShift = offset - start;
  ut.u8[1] = data[firstByte];
  ut.u8[0] = data[firstByte+1];
  return (ut.u16 >> numShift) & mask;
}
int main()
{
  ??????????
  uint8_t sB = 46;
  uint16_t l = 7;
  uint16_t extractValue = Frame2Data(?,sB,l);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: a bit unclear what you want, there's no such thing as "*hex data*". hexadecimal is just a way to write the data. A variable holding multiple bytes at once (e.g. an `unsigned long long`) is **not** necessarily the same as an array of bytes, because of [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). To get a proper answer, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50138637/edit) your question and create a [mcve].

Comment: @user8540390 With C99 code could use a _compound literal_: `Frame2Data((uint8_t [8]){ 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0xE8, 0},sB,l);`  But what is best depends on 1) how that data is created and 2) is it used after `Frame2Data()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass data written in hexadecimal to `data`, you can simply write:

```
uint8_t data [] = { 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xE8, 0x00};
```

Note that variable `mask` is uninitialized, because `l` is equal to 7 and all instructions to initialize variable `mask` are dead code, as show in red, with a source code analyzer:

https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/6d486c5b

Comment: Yes, since the length is equal to 7, mask is initialized to `0x7F`.

Comment: Yeah understood and got it.Thankyou